# Any Help with "Globetrotter"?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

Can anyone offer some assistance with the **Globetrotter** trophy?

> Awarded for setting foot in all secluded regions.

Does this include all of the tiny forest areas, caves, and so on? Is there a list somewhere or map that I can use to check off which ones are left? Or is there something in-game that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two images are from IGN and show the locations of caves and forest dwellings.

[image]

[image]

Some of these locations are found in the story. If you visit the IGN map (http://www.ign.com/maps/ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch/world), you can filter for the locations and then select the bubble to determine whether or not it is found in the story.

This image was posted on a Japanese website, but is incomplete.

[image: Secluded Area Map]

The red triangles indicate secluded areas that you will encounter during the story. As long as you play through the story and side quests you will not need to search for these. There is also a region, south of Ding Dong Dell, that only opens once finishing the main story.

The purple triangles indicate the locations of secluded areas that are not linked to any quest and are only found accidentally or with a systematic search (or with a map like this).

The colored letters indicate locations of regenerating items (the sparkly star spots), such as flora and spring water, and can be disregarded for your purposes.

Map from: http://dswiipspwikips3.jp/ninokuni/map.html

Comment: Are you sure this map is complete?  I made sure to check off each as I visited. I count a total of 16 purple triangles if anyone would care to confirm.

Comment: I've added another map that I used, but you will need to follow the IGN link in the answer to identify which locations are part of the story.

Comment: I also count 16 purple triangles.

Comment: The IGN and Japanese maps overlap, however. I am not aware of any other Globetrotter areas other than what has been indicated on these maps.

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed something and will make another run through each area.

Comment: No problem. Did you try again and find everything?